# Silverlight Control Toolkit debugging symbols

Tags: visual-studio-2008, silverlight, debugging

Does the Silverlight Control Toolkit have debug symbols available anywhere?  I know the source is distributed and I could just build that and reference the newly-built assemblies and their symbols, but that's lame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, we don't. We made the call thinking that anyone that needs them, could simply build them - and that way they'd have the source open, working, and improve that experience.

But I can agree that it's lame, knowing that someone's actually interested in the symbols. I'll see if we can't ship them next time around for at least the Silverlight Toolkit.